# Worst Case Big O with Java Algorithms

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o

1.

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        print i+j;
    }
}
```

I would assume Big O would be 30 since the most amount of times would be 3*10.

2.

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < m; j++){
        print i+j;
    }
}
```

Would be O be n*m?

3.

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < m; j++){
        for(int k = 1; k < 1000; k *= 2){
            print i+j+k;
        }
    }
}
```

n * m * log base 2 (1000) The Big O is in nlog(n) time

4.

```
for(i = 0; i < n - 10; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < m/2; j++){
        print i+j;
    }
}
```

5.

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
   print i;
}
//n and m are some integers
for(j = 1; j < m; j *= 2){
   print j;
}
```

Can someone give me a hand with this if you know Big O. I am looking at these and at a loss.  I hope I am posting this in the right location, I find these problems difficult. I appreciate any help.

Comment: `Big O would be 30` it is O(1) since 3 and 10 are both very small numbers. If they could be arbitrarily large, it would be O(N-squared)

Comment: Ok Big O of 1 makes sense. I guess 30 is correct too, but not the convention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's important just to point out that Big O notation is all about functions that, given an arbitrary constant, will be considered upper bounds at some point.

1. > O(1)

   This is because each loop iterates in a *constant amount of time*. We would refer to this as O(1) instead of O(30) because the function which is the upper bound is 1 with an arbitrary constant >=30.
2. > O(n*m)

   Simply because we have to loop through `m` iterations `n` times.
3. > O(n*m)

   This is the same as the previous one, only we're throwing in another loop in the middle. Now you can notice that this loop, similar to the first problem, is just a constant time. Therefore, you don't even need to really spend time figuring out how often it loops since it will always be constant - it is O(1) and would be interpreted as O(n*m*1) which we can simply call O(n*m)
4. > O(n*m)

   For the outer loop, don't get caught up on the `.. - 10` and realize that we can just say that loop runs in O(n). We can ignore that `.. - 10` for the same reason we ignored the exact values in the first problem; *constants don't really matter*. This same principle applies for the `m/2` because you can think of `m` just being manipulated by a constant of `1/2`. So we can just call this O(n*m).
5. > T(n) = O(n) + O(lg m) => O(n + lg m)

   So there are two components we have to look at here; the first loop and the second loop. The first loop is clearly O(n), so that's no problem. Now the second loop is a little tricky. Basically, you can notice that the iterator `j` is growing exponentially (notably power of 2's), therefore that loop will be running the inverse of exponentially (logarithmic). So this function runs in O(n + lg m).

Comment: Okay 5 makes a lot more sense. I gave the best rating before you made this post. I really appreciate it this answer you gave me.

Answer (score 1):

Any constant factor can be ignored. `O(30)` is equal to `O(1)`, which is what one would typically say for 1).

2) Just so.

3) in `O(n*m*log_2(1000))`, `log_2(1000)` is constant, so it's `O(n*m)`.

4) `O(n-10)` is same as `O(n)`. `O(m/2)` is same as `O(m)`. Thus, `O(n*m)` again.

5) Trivially `O(n)`.

6) `O(log_2(m))`.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help. I was on the right track for the most part with a couple missing occurrences. I gave you a upvote.

Comment: @ringø: The original formatting was really bad; I assumed they were two separate pieces of code.